# Cannot add Server 2016 Core cluster to SCVMM, Error 410

Tags: windows-server-2016, system-center, windows-server-core, scvmm

I'm trying to add a four host, Server 2016 Core Cluster to SCVMM 2016.

I keep getting the following error when SCVMM tries to install the agent on all four hosts:

```
Error (410)
Agent installation failed on co-hvsrv-10.ccac.org.
The dependency service does not exist or has been marked for deletion

Recommended Action
Try the operation again. If the problem persists, install the agent locally 
and then add the managed computer.
```

I've made sure the SCVMM service account and the RunAs account both have administrator privileges on the hosts.

I've made sure the WinRM service is running.

I don't see any related error events on the hosts. I can see Successful security events for the SCVMM RunAs account on the hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more research I've come to the conclusion that it is impossible.
The server cluster which I am working with was described to me to be a Server 2016 Core installation when in reality it is a Nano Server 2016 installation.
SCVMM cannot install the agent on these servers because Nano server lacks MSI installation capability.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/vmm/hyper-v-nano?view=sc-vmm-2016

"Add the VMM package, Microsoft-NanoServer-SCVMM-Package, to ensure that the VMM agent is part of the VHD.
Add the VMM compute package, Microsoft-NanoServer-SCVMM-Compute-Package, to ensure that the VHD has the Hyper-V role, and that you can manage the physical server using VMM. If you install this package, don't use the -Compute option for the Hyper-V role)."

I'm not sure if this can be done to the nano server after you have already built the image but you can remove one at a time and reimage and re-add.

Also:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/deploy-nano-server